# Capture values of a shuttle list

Tags: list, report, oracle-apex

I am using APex 4.2

I have a page (page 31) with a shuttle list. The list contains several job categories (a, e, x, c, etc). I have a button on that page that generates a report based on the selected job category. I click my button, a query runs, and it takes me to a report page (page 27). The query is along these lines

```
select * from 'table'
where (instr(':'||:P31_JOB_CATEGORY||':',':'||JOB_CATEGORY||':') > 0)
```

where P31_JOB_CATEGORY is represented by a shuttle list. This gives me the desired results on page 27, however, is there a way to capture each selected job category that was selected in the shuttle list on page 31 and pass it to page 27 to be displayed? It would be nice to have it stored in a concatenated string of some sort for easy handling, i.e. A, E, C, X.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. You have the value of the shuttle list on page 31, as you show by using the bind variable :P31_JOB_CATEGORY. On Page 27 in your report you use P31_JOB_CATEGORY. What exactly is the problem, just display :P31_JOB_CATEGORY on page 27?

Comment: Yes the bind variable. :P31_JOB_CATEGORY is in my query in the where clause. Wasn't sure how to extract the value from there. However, I have passed the shuttle list value, P31_JOB_CATEGORY,  to a variable on Page 27. But it only displays/passes one category in the shuttle list. I.E., if i choose F, G, and R in my shuttle list, only F gets passed to page 27. Hence, I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

The reason is in how shuttle values are saved to session state and how the apex URL is constructed.
Shuttle values are constructed, as you have seen, by concatenating the selected values with a colon. So for example, I have a shuttle on `ENAME` from `EMP`, select 3 values and submit the page. Session state for the shuttle is: `URUGUAY:HOWARD:M BENZ`.

Now say that you redirect to another page, setting an item with the value of this shuttle item. The URL will look like this:  `f?p=54687:6:100741653098795::NO::P6_TEXT:URUGUAY:HOWARD:M BENZ`

The apex URL is constructed by using colons. You putting values in there which has colons simply doesn't work for apex.
Solution? You could submit the page and use a computation to replace the colons, and then branch away to the destination page. 
For example, with my enames I'm replacing the colon with a ~: `URUGUAY~HOWARD~M BENZ`. On your destination page you can then use this value and adapt your sql or use a computation in before/after header to replace the seperator again.